# POD default initialisation if static and constructor if automatic?

Tags: c++, struct, static, object-initializers

In the example below, Y and X give a warning "variable has static storage duration and non-POD type" (pclint, Autosar A3-3-2).

```
struct Y {int t; Y() {t = 0;}};
class X {private: int t; public: X() {t = 0;}};
struct Z {int t;};

X x; // warning: variable 'x' has 'static' storage duration and non-POD type
Y y; // variable 'y' has 'static' storage duration and non-POD type
Z z;
```

I have 2 questions.

1. What could happen before the constructor is called which justifies the warning?

Edit: In my case the global variable is only used in the standard namespace and data is accessed by global functions in this namespace. Therefore the constructor should be executed before data is accessed.

2. How can I avoid the warning which occurs for Y and X? I want to avoid possible uninitialised state if used with automatic storage (as for Z), therefore I would like to keep the constructor or reach the goal somehow else.

One solution could be the use of a C++ wrapper class which would initialise the struct. Is there a simpler/alternative solution, where uninitialised use of member "int t" cannot occur?

Comment: `pclint, Autosar A3-3-2` -- Wouldn't any "fixes" require knowledge of the `pclint` product?

Comment: I am just evaluating it for 1 day and I know that I could avoid that the warning is produced. But I would like to have a solution which is independent of pclint (maybe the warning is justified? - question 1). I am curious if there would be another solution using C++ and not parameters for the static checker.

Answer (score 1):

From [the AutoSAR C++14 Guidelines](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/adaptive/18-10/AUTOSAR_RS_CPP14Guidelines.pdf):

> **Rule A3-3-2 (required, implementation, automated)**
>
> Static and thread-local objects shall be constant-initialized.
>
> *Rationale*
>
> In general, using non-const global and static variables obscures the
> true dependencies of an API, since they can be accessed from any place
> of the source code. It therefore makes the code more difficult to
> maintain, less readable, and significantly less testable.
>
> A particular problem is that the order in which constructors and
> initializers for static variables are called is only partially
> specified by the C++ Language Standard and can even change from build
> to build. This can cause issues that are difficult to find or debug.
>
> [...]

---

> What could happen before the constructor is called which justifies the warning?

The general rationale for the rule is to avoid the complex rules of where dynamic initialization applies for static initialization, a common cause for e.g. the static initialization fiasco.

---

> How can I avoid the warning which occurs for Y and X? I want to avoid possible uninitialised state if used with automatic storage (as for Z), therefore I would like to keep the constructor or reach the goal somehow else.

A simply fix for your examples is to make their constructors `constexpr`, such that the `static` storage duration objects `x` and `y` are [constant-initialized instead of zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization) as part of static initialization:

> Constant initialization is performed instead of zero initialization of
> the static and thread-local (since C++11) objects and before all other
> initialization. Only the following variables are constant initialized:
>
> [...]
>
> 3. Static or thread-local object of class type that is initialized by a constructor call, **if the constructor is constexpr** and all
>    constructor arguments (including implicit conversions) are constant
>    expressions, **and if the initializers in the constructor's initializer
>    list and the brace-or-equal initializers of the class members only
>    contain constant expressions.**

E.g. (moving the initialization of the `t` data member by a constant expression to its default member initializer):

```
struct Y {
    int t{0}; 
    constexpr Y() {}
};

class X {
 private: 
    int t{0}; 
 public: 
    constexpr X() {}
};

X x;  // static initialization is constant-initialization
Y y;  // static initialization is constant-initialization
```

or alternatively initializing the `t` member in the member initializer list of the `constexpr` constructor:

```
struct Y {
    int t; 
    constexpr Y() : t{0} {}
};

class X {
 private: 
    int t; 
 public: 
    constexpr X() : t{0} {}
};
```

---

Finally, note that POD is no longer a standardese term as of C++11 (deprecated), and as the AutoSAR C++14 Guidelines naturally applies for C++14, one should consider entirely dropping the notion of POD class types; this likewise applies for pclint.

Comment: Unfortunately the warning does not disappear using any of your 4 variants.

Comment: What about if you used direct-braced-init? `X x{};`.

Comment: Same behaviour.

Comment: @ErnieMur My own experience with pclint, from using it over several years on a C++03 code base, enforcing MISRA C++:2008, was it was not the best tool for the job. I also got the feeling they were slow to update for modern safety standards and language standards; the mention of a ”POD-type” for a static analysis tool intended for a safety standard based on C++14 is mumbojumbo.

Comment: @ErnieMur You may want to look into and compare with other tools that have support for static analysis over AutoSAR C++14; e.g. Perforce’s Helix QAC, Synopisis’ Coverity, and others. LDRA is another option, but last I tried it (some 2 years ago) it was very poor on any non-C like C++ (couldn’t handle templates at all).